# Check all MySQL tables at once

Tags: mysql

I'd like to run a `CHECK TABLE` on all my tables from the MySQL command-line.

I can do it for a single table:

```
mysql> check table Restaurant;
+--------------------+-------+----------+----------+
| Table              | Op    | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+--------------------+-------+----------+----------+
| foodbox.Restaurant | check | status   | OK       |
+--------------------+-------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Is there an equivalent command that would **check all tables in the current database**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simplify your life with a shell script. Here is one I created for Linux, it is based on the [mysqlcheck](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html) application

This script will check all tables in all databases except mysql and information_schema

```
vi check_all_databases.sh

#!/bin/bash
USER=root
Port=3306
PASSWD=password

DBS="$(/usr/bin/mysql --connect_timeout 10 -u $USER -P $Port -p$PASSWD -Bse 'SHOW DATABASES')"
for db in $DBS
        do
                if [ "$db" != "mysql" ] && [ "$db" != "information_schema" ];
                then
                        /usr/bin/mysqlcheck -u $USER -p$PASSWD -c $db
                fi
        done
```

Save the file

```
\wq
```

Then execute it

```
sh check_all_databases.sh

dbt2.customer                                      OK
dbt2.district                                      OK
dbt2.history                                       OK
dbt2.item                                          OK
dbt2.new_order                                     OK
dbt2.order_line                                    OK
dbt2.orders                                        OK
```

For Windows you would use a batch script or vbs to do the same thing.

The other option would be just to run the mysqlcheck application for the one database you are interested in checking.

/path/to/mysqlcheck -u username -pPASSWORD -c database_name

mysqlcheck will be in the directory you installed your mysql binary files in.

In Linux, you can locate it with the which command

```
which mysqlcheck
```